# Asp.net Web API Attribute Routing 404 Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I cannot figure out for the life of me why my attribute routing isn't working.

Here is my setup:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Attribute routing
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "API Default",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

    }
}
```

Here is my controller with my routing attributes:

```
[Route("api/v1.0/orders")]
public class OrdersV1Controller
{

    [APIAuthentication(RequireAuthentication = true)]
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public GetOrderResponse GetOrder(int id)
    { 
      .....
    }
}
```

Here is my global asax file:

```
public class Global : HttpApplication
{
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.DefaultValueHandling.Populate;
    }
}
```

Here is the URL i'm testing which is returning a 404 not found:

`http://localhost:60105/api/v1.0/orders/111111`

Comment: have you considered `public class OrdersV1Controller : ApiController`

Comment: Wow i can't believe i missed that in all the examples... argh... that did it man.. add it as an answer so i can give you credit

Comment: hey - you and me both, i've been working on this for 2 days... lmao.. i feel so stupid.. haha thanks again man

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your controller needs to be an API Controller :

```
public class OrdersV1Controller : ApiController
```